# Intel i5 processor better than ATI HD Radeon GPU?

Tags: c++, opencl

In my application I am showing all available OpenCL devices so that the user can select the devices on which he wants to perform the computation.
The results I am getting on my laptop have left me befuddled.

[image]

Following is an excerpt of the code that produced these results:

```
//CL_DEVICE_TYPE
            {
                cl_device_type devtype;
                QString temp = "Unknown";
                err = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i][j], CL_DEVICE_TYPE, sizeof(devtype), &devtype, NULL);
                if(err == CL_SUCCESS)
                {
                    if(devtype == CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)
                        temp = "CPU";
                    else if(devtype == CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)
                        temp = "GPU";
                    else if(devtype == CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)
                        temp = "Accelerator";
                    else
                        temp = "Unkown";
                }
                ilist->append(temp);
            }

            //CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY
            {
                cl_uint devfreq;
                err = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i][j], CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY, sizeof(devfreq), &devfreq, NULL);
                if(err == CL_SUCCESS)
                    ilist->append(QString::number((unsigned int)devfreq));
                else
                    ilist->append("Unknown");
            }

            //CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE
            {
                cl_ulong devmem;
                err = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i][j], CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, sizeof(devmem), &devmem, NULL);
                devmem /= 1000000;
                if(err == CL_SUCCESS)
                    ilist->append(QString::number((unsigned int)(devmem)));
                else
                    ilist->append("Unkown");
            }

            //CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS * CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE
            {
                cl_uint devcores;
                err = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i][j], CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(devcores), &devcores, NULL);
                if(err == CL_SUCCESS)
                {
                    size_t devcores2;
                    err = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i][j], CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(devcores2), &devcores2, NULL);
                    if(err == CL_SUCCESS)
                        ilist->append(QString::number(((unsigned int)(devcores)) * ((unsigned int)(devcores2))));
                    else
                        ilist->append("Unkown");
                }
                else
                    ilist->append("Unknown");
            }
```

What I do not understand is the Memory and the no of parallel computations shown for the CPU.
Any idea why I am getting these results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE is not an indicator of parallel computation ability.

Comment: Is it counting Intel HD Graphics too? Because how can a CPU have this much work group size? And I understand that clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo() is a better indicator but it evident from the results that the CPU has better memory as well as parallel computations compared to the GPU?

Comment: No, integrated graphics shows up as a separate device. Max work group size is just an indication of how the runtime is able to do your work, not an indication of performance. clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo is also not an indication of performance. Clock frequency times compute units is a better indicator, but comparing across vendors is not typically "fair".

Comment: Then why is it not showing Intel HD Graphics 4000?According to http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/accelerate-performance-using-opencl-with-intel-hd-graphics it is supposed to be OpenCL 1.2 compatible while my application is 1.1 compatible? Is it because I am using the APP SDK?

Comment: I am getting 6 compute units for GPU while 4 for CPU? But GPU is supposed to be having substantially more parallel computing power. Then how can compute units only be an indicator of computability?

Comment: In OpenCL the workgroup size doesn't necessarily mean how many threads run in paralllel. It simply means how many threads can be synchronized  and access same local memory pool. So for a CPU a massive local size support is provided as a convenience feature, not as something that indicates performance. The Intel CPU actually has something like 8 as it's true local size per core on kernels that it was able to horizontally vectorize as SSE instructions.

Comment: From what I understand there is 1 work group per compute unit and each work item in a work group is capable of doing parallel processing. Correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's a complicated task - to measure device performance.

Metrics you used are not suitable to determine how fast device is. Moreover, simple tasks like matrix multiplication doesnt show it either. You need to use benchmarks to determine computing capabilities.

Comment: Agreed. For some problems I/O dominates, for others math dominates. Benchmarking is the only way to know.

Comment: I am not doing benchmarking in my software. It is just to give an idea of how fast a device is to a "non-power" user. What do you suggest I should show to the user?

Comment: Vendor, Device name, type, memory, compute units, and frequency. Your documentation can mention that compute units are not directly comparable across types and vendors.

Comment: OK I will do that. But why is Intel HD Graphics 4000 not showing up?

Comment: Check graphic settings for your application in AMD catalyst center.

Comment: dont know why but CCC is not showing a pop up after my application has terminated. It usually does this when an application using GPU terminates so that the user can select between 2 modes. I have a Windows gadget which tells when a GPU is running it is clearly showing that my application is using the ATI GPU.